# Pulumi local workspace config values, are these applicable to Azure deployments?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, automation, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

The following is example code from the Pulumi site that demonstrates Pulumi automation in C# for a simple AWS deployment. The last line of code shows how a region can be configured for a workspace.

Is the equivalent available when deploying Azure resources? I ask because I am hoping to avoid assigning an Azure location to each resource and instead specify the location globally within the workspace.

FYI In this context I believe a workspace is a Pulumi automation artifact.

```
    var stackArgs = new InlineProgramArgs(projectName, stackName, program);
    var stack = await LocalWorkspace.CreateOrSelectStackAsync(stackArgs);
    await stack.Workspace.InstallPluginAsync("aws", "v4.0.0");

    // set stack configuration specifying the region to deploy
    await stack.SetConfigAsync("aws:region", new ConfigValue("us-west-2"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so the equivalent for the [Pulumi Azure Native](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/cloud-providers/azure/) provider would be something like this:

```
var stackArgs = new InlineProgramArgs(projectName, stackName, program);
var stack = await LocalWorkspace.CreateOrSelectStackAsync(stackArgs);
await stack.Workspace.InstallPluginAsync("azure-native", "v1.14.0");

// set stack configuration specifying the region to deploy
await stack.SetConfigAsync("azure-native:location", new ConfigValue("uswest"));
```

So you'd swap the `aws` for `azure-native`, get the right version (the latest is v1.14.0 at the time of writing) and instead of region you'd have location.

Comment: Thanks for the full code example. One day I will have time to investigate Pulumi's open source and see how these workspace global config values are assigned to new resources behind the scenes. For now I will assume any resource with a property named "location" will be auto filled with the global workspace config value.